# Why the loop iterate less then declared?

Tags: c

I am making a simple vote counter, where voter number will be given by user. And I have to take char inputs from user and count them. but strangly my for loop terminating early every time. dont know why.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int num,i;
int ma=0;
int ca = 0;
int je = 0;
char cand;

printf("Number of voters: ");
scanf("%d", &num);

printf("Name of 1st Candidate: Max\n");
printf("Name of 2nd Candidate: Callum\n");
printf("Name of 3rd Candidate: Jesse\n");

   for(i=0; i<=num; i++){
   scanf("%c", &cand);
   switch(cand)
   {
       case 'm': 
       ma = ma+1;
       break;
       case 'c': 
    ca = ca+1;
       break;
       case 'j': 
       je= je+1;
       break;
       default:
       break;}}
       printf("%d %d %d", ma,ca,je);
        return 0;}
```

Comment: Please study & use the same coding style and indention that is used in your C programming book. After that, try to compile the code before posting it here. If you need help with understanding compiler errors, then quote the compiler errors.

Comment: @user3121023  oops it is working now. but what was the problem though? Just a space??????

Comment: @Lundin I have spent 1.5 hour on that could not find the problem. I am new though.

Comment: It was reading the newline left in the buffer after the previous `scanf("%d", &num);` and on the following iterations it reads the newline left from the previous `scanf("%c", &cand);` alternately with the character that was entered.

Comment: Ok then you can certainly spend 1 more minute copy/pasting this into a C compiler and fix all the obvious problems. Your coding style is going to be a massive cause of all manner of brace problems.

Comment: @user3121023 ok thats make sense now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you wrote as 'int main{'. As 'main' is a function, it needs to have '()' after 'main' which is used to get argument variables. So you should actually write 'int main(void){' instead of 'int main{' at the 2nd line.
I hope this works for you:)
(Also, 'void' means empty so the compiler which reads your code will no whether there is an argument variable for main function or not.)

Comment: thanks for pointing out, It was actually a typing error here but my original work has those brackets. Thanks again.

Comment: @Faisal it's a good idea to **copy/paste** your actual code, then you won't drive readers away with non-existent typos.

Comment: @WeatherVane yep make sense now, I was wondering why I got so many down votes. Any way thanks again.

Comment: I guess this is not really an answer and could be deleted